# Spring boot reset datasource on the fly

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to update datasource in Spring Boot when the DB property like DB name, password or hostname changes in the spring configuration file or custom DB property file. When the property changes the application has to update by its own by listening changes to property.

I was using Spring actuator to /restart beans once the DB configuration is changed. But user has to explicitly make a post request to restart. This step has to be avoided by listening to the changes and update datasource.

Can you tell me the best way to do this in Spring boot?

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44716195/refresh-database-configuration-on-the-fly/44717728#44717728

Comment: Blog by a Pivotal team member on this - https://aniruthmp.github.io/SpringBoot2-DB-Refresh/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found a way to update datasource on-the-fly,

I have given external spring config file which contains DB properties to the application and then refreshed the properties using @RefreshScope for the datasource bean.

A thread monitors the file changes and makes a call to actuator refresh() method.

database.properties

```
dburl=jdbc://localhost:5432/dbname
dbusername=user1
dbpassword=userpwd
```

Creating datasource,

```
@RefreshScope
public class DBPropRefresh {
  @Value("${dburl}")
  private String dbUrl;

  @Value("${dbusername}")
  private String dbUserName;

  @Value("${dbpassword}")
  private String dbPassword;

  @Bean
  @RefreshScope
  public DataSource getDatasource() {
    return new DatasourceBuilder().create().url(dbUrl).username(dbUserName).password(dbPassword);
  }
}
```

Giving external config file to the application,

`java -jar myapplication.jar --spring.config.location=database.properties`

I have created a Java thread class to monitor database.properties file changes. Followed https://dzone.com/articles/how-watch-file-system-changes
When there are changes then it makes call to refreshEndPoint.refresh().

In pom.xml,

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Awesome. I didn't know about the refresh scope in actuator. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @Walery When its refreshed, what happens to on going transactions?

Comment: @sandeep It will not be a problem... better to use a connection pool in this case

Comment: @vishnukumar. Would this interrupt the existing transactions ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring's Dynamic Data Source routing and check if it helps? It's a very old technique and might come handy, if that serves your purpose.

But please note that - this is data source routing and not new data source configuration.

https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/

Comment: Hi Karthik, I have gone through several of these data source routing but all be pre-defined datasources that can be connected on-the-fly. In my case, it requires to update to new datasource.

Comment: Is it possible to get the datasource bean and change its properties?

Comment: Out of the box, I don't think we can do that. You can have routing as I said. But to create one, not possible without a restart of container when the property is changed. Even if you need it to be that dynamic, it can only be upon JNDI lookup where you can get data source. I never had this requirement or need for this. May be Spring actuator is the only way you can go ahead as of now.

Comment: I dont think it is possible since the datasource is injected at context start

Comment: @StimpsonCat, I believe the same. context once loaded now cannot be reloaded for this one. Normal ResourceBundleMessageSource is not for this purpose either, though, at glance it seems it would help.

Answer (score 1):

In my project I used [multitenancy](https://fizzylogic.nl/2016/01/24/make-your-spring-boot-application-multi-tenant-aware-in-2-steps/) . Basically I defined several datasources in properties like this:

```
primary.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_name?currentSchema=schema_name
primary.datasource.username=user
primary.datasource.password=password
primary.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
primary.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

secondary.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/other_db?currentSchema=schema
secondary.datasource.username=user
secondary.datasource.password=password
secondary.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
secondary.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

default.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/default_db?currentSchema=public
default.datasource.username=user
default.datasource.password=password
default.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
default.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

then in configuration class defined multiple datasources:

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="primary.datasource")
public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="secondary.datasource")
public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="default.datasource")
public DataSource defaultDataSource(){
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

and configured multitenancy basing on [this](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-hibernate-multitenancy-implementation) and [this](https://fizzylogic.nl/2016/01/24/make-your-spring-boot-application-multi-tenant-aware-in-2-steps/) article. 
Pros:

- Easy tenant switch which could be triggered manually or even configured to be triggered on some specific header in request (filters).
- Could be cofigured to switch between schemas or databases.
- Happens dynamically ( you don't have to restart your beans )

Cons:

- You have to define all db possibilities in property file.
- You have to turn off schema validation because it will go nuts.