# How to set Spring Data Cassandra keyspace dynamically?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-cloud-config, spring-data-cassandra

We're using Spring Boot 1.5.10 with [Spring Data for Apache Cassandra](https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-cassandra/) and that's all working well.

We've had a new requirement coming along where we need to connect to a different keyspace while the service is up and running.

Through the use of Spring Cloud Config Server, we can easily set the value of `spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name`, however, we're not certain if there's a way that we can dynamically switch (force) the service to use this new keyspace without having to restart if first?

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `@RefreshScope` with properties/repositories doesn't work as the keyspace is bound to the Cassandra `Session` bean.

Using Spring Data Cassandra 1.5 with Spring Boot 1.5 you have at least two options:

1. Declare a `@RefreshScope` `CassandraSessionFactoryBean`, see also [`CassandraDataAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/1.5.x/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/cassandra/CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.java#L109). This will interrupt all Cassandra operations upon refresh and re-create all dependant beans.
2. Listen to `RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent` and change the keyspace via `USE my-new-keyspace;`. This approach is less invasive and doesn't interrupt running queries. You'd basically use an event listener.

   ```
   @Component
   class MySessionRefresh {

     private final Session session;
     private final Environment environment;

     // omitted constructors for brevity

     @EventListener
     @Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
     public void handle(RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent event) {

       String keyspace = environment.getProperty("spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name");
       session.execute("USE " + keyspace + ";");
     }
   }
   ```

With Spring Data Cassandra 2, we introduced the [`SessionFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/SessionFactory.html) abstraction providing [`AbstractRoutingSessionFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/cql/session/lookup/AbstractRoutingSessionFactory.html) for code-controlled routing of CQL/session calls.

Comment: thanks for your very thorough reply John. As I haven't worked with the event listeners before I just want to ask a follow up question. I really want to go with option 2 due to being less invasive, however, I'm a bit unclear to whether I need to create a separate listener class to the code that you have already provided? I haven't been able to find any examples of the use of a RefreshEvent, so a bit in the dark here :-)
I can see that the @Component is working and that the bean is created, however, I fail to trigger the handle() method. Cheers

Comment: I'm not John. Having an own class encapsulates all responsibility for keyspace change/refresh in the single class, you're not mixing aspects. That's however a format which fitted best in here instead of making up a config class...

Comment: Apologies for mixing up your name Mark :-)
I agree with your reasoning for encapsulating the responsibility, the problem I'm facing is that the handle() method isn't invoked when I call the /refresh endpoint on the service - do I need to register the event listener anywhere (I was of the understanding that it was done automatically)?

Comment: I got your solution working when using 'RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent' instead of 'RefreshEvent'. If you wouldn't mind updating your answer I can accept your solution as the most correct one. cheers

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I fixed answer and updated it to `RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent`.

Comment: With this solution first I created session.execute for creation of new keyspace if does not exists and after that the execution of using. But the problem here is that the schemas from the entities with @Table annotation are not automatically created in the new keyspace.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the [`@RefreshScope`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-commons-parent/1.1.5.RELEASE/org/springframework/cloud/context/config/annotation/RefreshScope.html) annotation on a the bean(s) holding the `spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name` value.

After changing the config value through Spring Cloud Config Server, you have to issue a POST on the `/refresh` endpoint of your application.

From the [Spring cloud documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/docs/1.0.x/spring-cloud.html#_refresh_scope):

> A Spring @Bean that is marked as @RefreshScope will get special treatment when there is a configuration change. This addresses the problem of stateful beans that only get their configuration injected when they are initialized. For instance if a DataSource has open connections when the database URL is changed via the Environment, we probably want the holders of those connections to be able to complete what they are doing. Then the next time someone borrows a connection from the pool he gets one with the new URL.

From the [RefreshScope class](http://static.javadoc.io/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-commons-parent/1.1.9.RELEASE/org/springframework/cloud/context/scope/refresh/RefreshScope.html) javadoc:

> A Scope implementation that allows for beans to be refreshed dynamically at runtime (see refresh(String) and refreshAll()). If a bean is refreshed then the next time the bean is accessed (i.e. a method is executed) a new instance is created. All lifecycle methods are applied to the bean instances, so any destruction callbacks that were registered in the bean factory are called when it is refreshed, and then the initialization callbacks are invoked as normal when the new instance is created. A new bean instance is created from the original bean definition, so any externalized content (property placeholders or expressions in string literals) is re-evaluated when it is created.

Comment: That's what we're doing but once that new keyspace has been set (after using /refresh), there is nothing that triggers the service to start using that new keyspace. I'm not sure if it's even possible because I think a restart is needed before the service will switch over to that new keyspace.

Comment: @ASC On which bean did you put the `@RefreshScope` annotation?

Comment: I put it on the controller class ( @RestController)

Comment: You should try to put it on the repository.

Comment: John Blum wrote on Twitter 'You can set the keyspace once for startup and then it’s intended to stay the same.', which indicates that what I'm trying to do isn't possible

Comment: You should maybe wait for a new release, at least it works for datasources : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46031944/spring-boot-reset-datasource-on-the-fly