Spring Data Cassandra customizing CqlSession and load properties from application.yml automatically?
I want to acquire the CqlSession Builder to customize my CqlSession when using Spring Data Cassandra.
As I already put keyspace-name and local-datacenter in my application.yml, I hope something like the following would work.
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = { "tacos" })
public class CassandraConfig  {

    @Bean
    CqlSession cassandraSession() {
        CqlSession delegate = CqlSession.builder().build();
        return new MyCqlSession(delegate);
    }

}

The application.yml:
spring:
  data:
    cassandra:
      keyspace-name: taco_cloud
      schema-action: recreate
      local-datacenter: datacenter1

But the above snippet does not load properties from application.yml.
I have to read properties manually like the following to work around.
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = { "tacos" })
public class CassandraConfig  {

    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name}")
    public String keyspace;

    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.local-datacenter}")
    public String localDatacenter;

    @Bean
    CqlSession cassandraSession() {
        CqlSession delegate = CqlSession.builder().withKeyspace(keyspace)
        .withLocalDatacenter(localDatacenter).build();
        return new MyCqlSession(delegate);
    }

}


How are you expecting it to work in the first code snippet exactly?

@ryanwebjackson I would love the cqlsession builder to pick up the properties I specify in application.yml, such as keyspace-name.

But how would it do that, mechanically? Are you thinking there is code inside the the CqlSession Builder that reads from environment variables, and that the YAML values are also being loaded as environment variables? If so, I don't think it's set up to work that way. All of the documentation I read, the Builder class requires you to pass a string name for the keyspace. https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.2/manual/core/index.html https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/4.6/com/datastax/oss/driver/api/core/CqlSessionBuilder.html

Here is a way to dynamically change keyspace, but I don't think that's exactly what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48782031/2125723
